# NGINX Default Page

Tags: nginx, default, html

In  `NGINX` server my index page placed in sub folders not in root of site,
(for example `/root/pages/htmls/index.html`)
How can I map `index.html` page as default web page of site?

Comment: Questions about server configuration are off topic here and belong on serverfault.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try following code,

```
...
server {
   ...
   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /pages/htmls/index.html;
   }
   ...
}
...
```